# How to optimize my query to get result faster?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization, phpexcel

I am scanning the words on many web pages and then store them in MySQL db.

I have three tables:

- **words**: (*wordid*, *word*)
- **pages**: (*pageid*, *page*)
- **map**: (*wordid*, *pageid*, *freq*)

freq field is for holding occurences of a word in a page.

Then using PHPExcel, I am creating a sheet in which words, pages and frequency values reside.

The basic scheme of the sheet is as the following:

```
|   A   |   B   |   C   | ....
|       |page1  |page2  | ....
|word1  |     10|      7| ....
|word2  |      2|      1| ....
...
...
```

So I have the following code for getting that Excel sheet but required time to work takes too long and the browser stops working, says that the server responds too late. So my work does not finish. I have also tried to add

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(36000);
```

but there is no change before and after adding the code above.

So I think now that optimizing query may result faster.

```
function write2excel($config)
{
    include 'PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    include 'PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

     //retrieve page names from DB in a associative array
     $pages = getPages($config);

     //retrieve word names from DB in a associative array
     $words = getWords($config); 

    $r = 1;
    $c = 0;

     //Write each word into the first column in each row.
    foreach ($words as $w)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $r, $w['word']);
        $r++;
    }
     //Write page names into the first rows of each column
    foreach ($pages as $p)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($c, 2, $p['page']);
        $c++;
    }

     $c = 1;
    foreach ($words as $w)
    {
        $r = 2;
        foreach ($pages as $p)
        {
            $freq = getFrequency($p['page'], $w['word'], $config);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($c, $r, $freq);

             $r++;
        }
        $c++;
    }

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('mySheet');

    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);

    $objWriter->save('mySheet.xlsx');
 }

function getWords($config)
{
    require_once $config . '.php';

    $conn = new Connection();

    $query = $conn->db->query('SELECT word FROM words');

    $query->execute();

    return $query->FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function getPages($config)
{
    require_once $config . '.php';

    $conn = new Connection();

    $query = $conn->db->query('SELECT page FROM pages');

    $query->execute();

    return $query->FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function getFrequency($page, $word, $config)
{
    require_once $config . '.php';

    $conn = new Connection();

    //find frequency value of the given word for the given page
    $query = $conn->db->prepare('SELECT freq FROM map WHERE pageid IN '
            . '(SELECT pageid FROM pages WHERE page = :page) '
            . 'AND wordid IN (SELECT wordid FROM words WHERE word = :word) LIMIT 1');

    $query->bindValue(':page', $page, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':word', $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $query->execute();

    $row = $query->FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $freq = $row[0]['freq'];
    }
    else
    {
        $freq = 0;
    }
    return $freq;
}
```

I have more than 10000 rows in table **words** and more than 1000 rows in table **pages**

**EDIT**

How could it be done that if I want to run this script 100-by-100 rows for all pages? I mean the first 100 words will be fetched and then 101-200, 201-300, ... till the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uploaded my program to a web server which I thought it is superior to my laptop. But I got no solution. So I decided to divide the result sets using `limit` and `offset`.

I enter limit and offset values using addressbar. I am now getting my sheets. Then I am going to merge them into a single sheet.

Thanks for your suggestions. I have applied them to my code. I did not measure if they have accelerated my work but seemed that makes sense.

Anyway my problem has been solved.

I have changed the function getWords() as the following:

```
function getWords($config, $limit, $offset)
{
    require_once $config . '.php';

    $conn = new Connection();

    $query = $conn->db->query('SELECT word FROM words LIMIT ' . $limit . ' OFFSET ' . $offset );

    $query->execute();

    $rows = array();
    while($row =$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        $rows[]= $row;
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

I know the query is vulnerable, prone to injections. Who cares? I already run it on my local computer.

Answer (score 1):

You should check where the exact problem is, but you can already improve some things:

- Use only one connection and pass that around so that you don't open a new database connection every time you call one of your functions;
- Prepare your statement once and then execute it multiple times instead of preparing it each time in the function when you call that function.

Apart from that, executing queries in loops (or in nested loops in this case), is always going to be a problem so trying to reduce the number of queries and using [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to optimize your indices are probably going to give the biggest gains.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally notice that fetching all rows at once is very expensive.

Using `fetch()` to fetch your record one by one would so much faster, try applying these changes:

```
function getWords($config)
{
    require_once $config . '.php';

    $conn = new Connection();

    $query = $conn->db->query('SELECT word FROM words');

    $query->execute();

    $rows = array();
    while($row =$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        $rows[]= $row;
    }

    return $rows;
}

function getPages($config)
{
    require_once $config . '.php';

    $conn = new Connection();

    $query = $conn->db->query('SELECT page FROM pages');

    $rows = array();
    while($row =$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        $rows[]= $row;
    }

    return $rows;
}

function getFrequency($page, $word, $config)
{
    require_once $config . '.php';

    $conn = new Connection();

    //find frequency value of the given word for the given page
    $query = $conn->db->prepare('SELECT freq FROM map WHERE pageid IN '
            . '(SELECT pageid FROM pages WHERE page = :page) '
            . 'AND wordid IN (SELECT wordid FROM words WHERE word = :word) LIMIT 1');

    $query->bindValue(':page', $page, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':word', $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $query->execute();

    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $freq = $row['freq'];
    }
    else
    {
        $freq = 0;
    }
    return $freq;
}
```